# How to configure SSH username and pass on Ubuntu server 14.04.1

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

I am trying to remotely administer my server using SSH. I believe SSH comes installed default, I just need to know how to configure username and password.

Comment: I should have specified I am using the server ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need to know how to configure username and password.

`ssh` uses the same usernames and passwords as the system it is running on.

In other words, a username and password that you can use to login to the system from the keyboard will also work when logging in via ssh.

(Some of this can be changed via the config files but you indicate that you are just using default configuration.)

Comment: That's what I figured. The only reason I thought differently is because I am using webmin to remotely administer, and when I enter in my username and pass under SSH login it isn't connecting.

Comment: So I have no problem with ssh login from terminal, but whenever I try webmin's ssh login it fails, oh well at least terminal works.

Comment: How would I exit the ssh session?

Comment: @Skateguy To exit a ssh connection, exit whatever program ssh is running.  Typically, ssh runs a shell, e.g. bash.  In that case, type exit or control-D and ssh will terminate as soon as the shell terminates.  On the other issue, I have never used webmin so you may want to ask a separate question about webmin configuration.